# How to get Bluetooth Headset connection state on application start-up using Android2.2?

Tags: android, bluetooth, headset

How to get Bluetooth Headset connection state (connected/disconnected) using android api level 8 on application start-up?
Is there any sticky broadcast intent available in android2.2?
Is there any API to fetch initial Bluetooth Headset state?
Is there any workaround available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the solution:

```
private static final String ACTION_BT_HEADSET_STATE_CHANGED  = "android.bluetooth.headset.action.STATE_CHANGED";
private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 0x00000002; 
private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED  = 0x00000000;  
private static final String EXTRA_STATE = "android.bluetooth.headset.extra.STATE";

private BroadcastReceiver mBlueToothHeadSetEventReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if(action == null)
            return;

        if(action.equals(ACTION_BT_HEADSET_STATE_CHANGED)){
            int extraData = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_STATE  , STATE_DISCONNECTED);
            if(extraData == STATE_CONNECTED ){

                //TODO :

            }else if(extraData == STATE_DISCONNECTED){

                //TODO:
            }
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        //TODO:

        }
}
};
```

Comment: On my device (Motorola Milestone 2 aka Droid 2) this intent (android.bluetooth.headset.action.STATE_CHANGED) does NOT seem to be STICKY, that means on application startup, when registering the BroadcastReceiver for this intent, it always returns NULL, even if the headset is in connected state. I also registered a filter for android.media.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED and it DOES report the audio state on startup, which is of course not enough, because this will in most cases be SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED and does not mean that no headset is connected. Is this a device specific behavior?

Answer (score 0):

from packages/apps/Phone/src/com/android/phone/PhoneGlobals.java:1449

```
        } else if (action.equals(BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            mBluetoothHeadsetState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothHeadset.EXTRA_STATE,
                                                      BluetoothHeadset.STATE_DISCONNECTED);
            if (VDBG) Log.d(LOG_TAG, "mReceiver: HEADSET_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION");
            if (VDBG) Log.d(LOG_TAG, "==> new state: " + mBluetoothHeadsetState);
            updateBluetoothIndication(true);  // Also update any visible UI if necessary
```

Answer (score -1):

This won't really work on application startup, but as intent-filters are registered automatically, you might have a valid value, once your app gets started up:

Declare the following intent-filter

```
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.headset.action.AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and in your Receiver in onReceive check for:

```
if ("android.bluetooth.headset.action.AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
  headsetAudioState = intent.getIntExtra("android.bluetooth.headset.extra.AUDIO_STATE", -2);
}
```

and save the int as a static variable. Access it anytime you want to know if BT audio is connected(1) / disconnected(0). Not pretty, but gets the job done.

Also check out:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/gingerbread/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.java

Comment: To my opinion, this won't help. It tells, if there is an active audio connection. If the headset is connected, the audio connection is NOT established automatically. BUT you should register this event latest when acquiring an audio connection on your own (by invacation of startBluetoothSco()), because then you can react on the AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED to start whatever you need to do when the audio channel is ready to use.