# Bluetooth connection with car

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to check when my device is connected with a car. I assume the car acts like a bluetooth headset, therefore I have used the following code in my activity onCreate:

```
    // Get the default adapter
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mProfileListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
        public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
            Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
            today.setToNow();
            if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
                mBluetoothHeadset = (BluetoothHeadset) proxy;

                LogginUtil.logString("BluetoothApp", "Headset event called at " + today.format("%k:%M:%S") + " - " + profile);
            } else {
                LogginUtil.logString("BluetoothApp", "Other event called at " + today.format("%k:%M:%S") + " - " + profile);
            }
        }
        public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
            if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
                mBluetoothHeadset = null;
                Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
                today.setToNow();
                LogginUtil.logString("BluetoothApp", "Headset event disconnected at " + today.format("%k:%M:%S"));
            }
        }
    };
    // Establish connection to the proxy.
    mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(getApplicationContext(), mProfileListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);
```

When I start the application, with bluetooth on and off, I get the following output:

```
Headset event called at "current time" - 1
```

When I pair my device with the car I get exactly the same output:

```
Headset event called at "current time" - 1
```

What do I need to do to detect that my device is actively connected via bluetooth with the car?

Thank you in advance, and let mw know if you require anything else.

**EDIT CLARIFICATION**

Just in case my question in misunderstood. I want to get notified (just a log) when the device goes into the state of being connected to a car via bluetooth. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to just a regular bluetooth headset?

Comment: apologies, just read your question fully, but definitely try with just a regular bluetooth headset first if there continue to be complications.

Comment: No, the aim of the game is to connect to 'n bluetooth enabled car. If the above code is wrong for that purpose, please point e in the right direction :), @bernlim

Comment: Understood. What I am advising you to do is make sure your code works in connecting with a simpler bluetooth headset first before attempting the more complicated car system. It should be easier to debug (i imagine you're sitting in your car trying to type this out or in the squeezy garage)

Comment: @bernlim, Lol, easier said than done, I can see the point of it, this may seem weird. I have a bluetooth enabled car close by, but not a bluetooth enabled headset :), so much for stepping stones right?

Comment: Haha I see. Well, we all have our share of weird requests. Check my suggestion below and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to try it right now, but perhaps this could work:

```
int[] validStates = {BluetoothHeadset.STATE_AUDIO_CONNECTED};
List<BluetoothDevice> mConnectedDevices =
  mBluetoothHeadset.getDevicesMatchingConnectionStates(validStates);
if (!mConnectedDevices.isEmpty()) {
    // You've got something connected here
}
```

Sources:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothProfile.html#getConnectedDevices()

Comment: Please see my edit. I think this would work to get the connected bluetooth audio devices. Please see my edit, I have explained my question in further detail. Please have a look, I realised this morning that it may be slightly unclear, thanks regardless!

Comment: @Lunchbox I was thinking that you could put that snippet inside your `onServiceConnected` method

Comment: I did implement something similar fix, the code is only slightly different. I will update with my answer as soon as I have time. You pointed me in the right direction so +1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A quick google found this answer, it worked for quite a few people so I am pretty sure it should work for you. Source: [How to get Bluetooth Headset connection state on application start-up using Android2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474928/how-to-get-bluetooth-headset-connection-state-on-application-start-up-using-andr)

```
private static final String ACTION_BT_HEADSET_STATE_CHANGED  = "android.bluetooth.headset.action.STATE_CHANGED";
private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 0x00000002; 
private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED  = 0x00000000;  
private static final String EXTRA_STATE = "android.bluetooth.headset.extra.STATE";

private BroadcastReceiver mBlueToothHeadSetEventReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if(action == null)
            return;

        if(action.equals(ACTION_BT_HEADSET_STATE_CHANGED)){
            int extraData = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_STATE  , STATE_DISCONNECTED);
            if(extraData == STATE_CONNECTED ){

                //TODO :

            }else if(extraData == STATE_DISCONNECTED){

                //TODO:
            }
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        //TODO:

        }
}
};
```

Comment: Looks like the event does not fire when connected to a car. I will post the solution when I find it.